# Grid Columns Without Rows?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a 3 column layout using the CSS Grid spec but I'm running into an issue with rows and element sizing. My columns need to contain an unspecified amount of content with varying heights.

This is my ideal layout:

[image]

**Problems:**

**1)** If I tell element A and B to use row 1, column 1 then they stack on top of one another rather than B below A.

**2)** If I specify element B to use the second row, then it gets pushed below element C due to element C making row 1 tall.

[image]

**3)** If I specify element B to use the second row, then element A stretches to fill row 1.

[image]

Is there any way to get elements to behave like in the first picture?

The only solution I know of is to create "scaffolding" divs inside the columns like this:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="itemA"></div>
        <div class="itemB"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="itemC"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="itemD"></div>
        <div class="itemE"></div>
        <div class="itemF"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I dislike doing that and I thought the grid spec was supposed to allow for layout creation without scaffolding.

**Questions:**

**1)** Is there any way to prevent elements from stretching to fill the row vertically?

**2)** Is it possible to put two elements on the same row and have them appear one below the other instead of conflicting?

Here's my 2 pens where I'm attempting to find a solution with and without scaffolding:

[Without scaffolding](https://codepen.io/Andronomos/pen/zapVYo?editors=1100)

[With scaffolding](https://codepen.io/Andronomos/pen/ERoBEb?editors=1100)

Comment: All direct children of a grid are grid items, so you define 2 columns and you have 5 direct children, they will stack to become 2 columns with 3 rows, You probably can get away with spanning columns and rows

Comment: I would point out what you are trying to do **is not a grid** so CSS-Grid is not the right tool here.

Comment: When you say "define columns" do you mean using grid-template-columns or the scaffolding I talked about? I'm trying to avoid scaffolding as I'd like my html to be as lean as it can be while functioning properly.

Also, I'm looking for 3 columns and preferably no rows if possible. I want it to look like the first picture I posted. Which I can only accomplish with scaffolding.

Comment: Flexbox - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/OEQLVO?editors=1100

Comment: I was trying to avoid using flexbox even though my layout is 1 dimensional because it requires scaffolding. So basically there's no way to create this layout without using scaffolding either with grid or flexbox?

Comment: As I said, what you are trying to do...is not a grid, so you have to use the right tool to do the job.

Comment: `I'd like my html to be as lean as it can be while functioning properly.` To keep it clean you have to use the right tool Like @Paulie_D said flexbox is way way more accurate for something like this, you only want columns, well flexbox goes one direction, whereas grid, care about about both of them

Comment: I understand. Do you think my distaste for scaffolding is irrational? It just seems like bad code to me.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa I understand that, I only chose grid because I was under the impression that it would allow me to create the layout without scaffolding and if I do end up using scaffolding, the code is exactly the same with either tool.

Comment: Nothing wrong with avoiding scaffolding where possible - I'm just not sure how much you can avoid it in this case.

Comment: Especially as the *weight* of the scaffolding is negligible.

Comment: Understood, you guys have convinced me. Scaffolding aside, how about my question regarding element stretching? Can it be disabled so an element only fills the row as much as it needs to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest i could have, but i do recommend you to use flexbox, You can't only define columns in CSS grids, the browsers will define rows for you, if you don't, and you don't manage them, you will get weird layout.

I hard coded the difference in heights between elements.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  background: brown;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid>div {
  background-color: orange;
}

.itemA {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.itemB {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  height: 200px;
}

.itemC {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  height: 200px;
}

.itemD {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.itemE {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  height: 100px;
}

.itemF {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="itemA">A</div>
  <div class="itemB">B</div>
  <div class="itemC">C</div>
  <div class="itemD">D</div>
  <div class="itemE">E</div>
  <div class="itemF">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I looking for. The ability to have content with different heights on different rows that don't stretch in 3 separate columns without any scaffolding.

Comment: I suppose you just didn't manage the rows, that were automatically generated.

Comment: I knew it was possible with the grid spec, i just couldn't remember how and my Google fu was failing me, lol.

Comment: it may be possible, it depends on what is the right tool to use, you can achieve many things, in a ton of ways, but which one is the right and most optimized way.

Comment: This code is for a sub section of a page and I may need to adjust the content positioning depending on browser width, would you still recommend flexbox?